# exclude BootstrapConfiguration classes in spring boot for tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, spring-test

I have an application which reads its configuration properties from Zookeeper instance.

There is one internal spring-boot-auto-configure module which helps in reading the information from zookeeper instance.

We need to set the zookeeper instance information in `bootstrap.properties` file.

**spring.factories from auto-configure module**

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
  com.company.name.ZooKeeperAutoConfig
```

There are also AutoConfiguration classes in the same file

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.company.name.XyzAutoConfig
```

So when application starts, it gets the info from bootstrap.properties and connect to zookeeper instance via auto-configure-module.

I want to write tests for Spring API controller layer using `@WebMvcTest` annotation.
But even in tests it tries to connect to zookeeper instance, which I dont want. I dont want unit tests talking to external services.

I want to exclude the zookeeper bootstrap configuration during tests.

Few ways I have tried without any luck.

1) I tried to exclude like following, but still it connects to Zookeeper

```
@TestPropertySource(properties=
{"spring.autoconfigure.exclude=com.company.name.ZooKeeperAutoConfig"})
```

2) I created bootstrap-test.properties and added some dummy values for zookeeper properties. And in test I added `@ActiveProfile("test")` . This tries to connect to zookeeper via dummy values and fails in the end.

Is there any way I can totally ignore/exclude the Zookeeper bootstrap configuration. Application should not aware that it needs to connect to zookeeper to be working.

Is it feasible to exclude BootstrapConfiguration in tests or not?

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue as you;
here are properties I don't want to load in my unit test,

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.alibaba.cloud.nacos.NacosConfigBootstrapConfiguration
```

`NacosConfigBootstrapConfiguration` defines as this:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.cloud.nacos.config.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class NacosConfigBootstrapConfiguration {
}
```

I fixed the issue through:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@Slf4j
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=
        {NacosConfigAutoConfiguration.class, NacosConfigEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.cloud.nacos.config.enabled=false"})
public class XXXDemo {}
```

this line `@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.cloud.nacos.config.enabled=false"})` takes effect!

Answer (score 0):

As an idea - have you tried to put a `@Conditional` annotation on your ZooKeeper Auto Configuration class?

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOn....
public class com.company.name.ZooKeeperAutoConfig  {
}
```

I can't check this by myself but maybe conditional on property could be relevant or, `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnNotWebApplication` that is supposed to match if the application context is not a web application context (but test appplication context relevant for tests)

Comment: I don't have access to ZooKeeperAutoConfig  code. Its a dependency as a jar in pom.xml

Comment: Sorry I'm confused now, you've said in the question "There is one internal spring-boot-auto-configure module..." and then you've mentioned package of (as I've assumed) your company `com.company.name.ZooKeeperAutoConfig`. Is it a jar developed in your organization or you're using some externally developed solution? For example, if its spring cloud (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper/blob/master/spring-cloud-zookeeper-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/zookeeper/ZookeeperAutoConfiguration.java) then it has a property `spring.cloud.zookeeper.enabled`